# OpenCV: link error, can't resolve external symbol _cvResize and _cvCvtColor

Tags: dll, opencv, linker, unresolved-external

the reason for the link error is clear, some lib is missing within my link procedure. Unfortunately it seems OpenCV 2.4.1 has changed it's internal structure, so the resolutions I find with Google/the Stackoverflow search function only recommend me to link against libraries that no longer exist (cv.lib or cxcore.lib).

I could solve some of my linking problems by using opencv_core241.lib and opencv_highgui241.lib, but in where are _cvResize and _cvCvtColor located at?

Comment: On Mac, I have it in the `imgproc`library. Maybe this helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated by guitarflow linking against opencv_imgproc241.lib is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Mmy problem was solved by adding the following libraries:
1- libopencv_highgui.2.4.7.dylib
2- libopencv_core.2.4.7.dylib
3- libopencv_imgproc.2.4.7.dylib

Regards.