# OpenCV installation, unresolved external symbols

Tags: c++, opencv, linker, unresolved-external

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [OpenCV: link error, can’t resolve external symbol _cvResize and _cvCvtColor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095375/opencv-link-error-cant-resolve-external-symbol-cvresize-and-cvcvtcolor)
>   [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

I have tried all of the tutorials available on their website, and the solutions on stackoverflow, but i still can't find a solution.

What I have already done:

1- added include folder with the headers.

2- added lib folder to the additional lib directories

3- added opencv_core243d.lib and opencv_highgui243d.lib to additional dependencies.

code i'm trying to compile:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
if (argc < 2)
{
    printf("Usage: ./opencv_hello <file.png>\n");
    return -1;
}

    IplImage* img = cvLoadImage(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
if (!img)
{
    return -1;
}
cvNamedWindow("display", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cvShowImage("display", img );

    cvWaitKey(0);        

    return 0;
}
```

The linker gives errors concerning unresolved symbols such as cvLoadImage, cvWaitKey etc.
The only thing i can think of would be the libs, but i have included them already.

Comment: @BoPersson also tried that, same errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you're using the OpenCV 2.4

In this case I would like to suggest using of the C++ interface.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

if (argc < 2)
{
    printf("Usage: ./opencv_hello <file.png>\n");
    return -1;
}

cv::Mat img = imread(argv[1]);
if (img.empty())
{
   return -1;
}

imshow("display", img);

waitKey(0); <---- cvWaitKey() is a C interface functio, waitKey() - C++

return 0;
}
```

Comment: After doing this, i still get the same linker errors.

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski on which one function?

Comment: now at !img, no operator found which takes cv::Mat as operand

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski try img.empty()

Comment: had a few other problems, but solved them just now. Thanks Alex!